# Returning specifically shaped POCOs to ASP.NET MVC actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, soa, api-design

In my ASP.NET MVC project, my actions typically call a Service layer to get data. I use the same dozen or so POCOs for all my models. I also plan on using the Service layer in console applications and maybe expose a web api at some point.

To make my database operations more efficient, my service layer only hydrates the properties in the model that are relevant to the particular method (which at this point is mostly driven by the needs of my controller actions).

So for example I might have a class `Order` with properties `Id, Name, Description, Amount, Items`. For a given service call I might only need to populate `Id, Name, Items`. A consumer of that service won't necessarily know that `Amount` is 0 only because it didn't populate the property.

Similarly, the consumer won't know whether `Items` is empty b/c there actually aren't any items, or whether this particular service method just doesn't populate that property.

And for a third example, say one of my views displays an `ItemCount`. I don't want to fully populate my `Items` collection, I just need an additional property on my "model". I don't want to add this property to my POCO that other service methods will be using because it's not going to be populated anywhere else.

So the natural solution is to make a POCO designed specifically for that method with only those 3 properties. That way the consumer can know that all properties will be populated with its real values. The downside to this is that I'll end writing tons of similarly shaped models.

Any advice on which method works best?

Comment: How many combinations are we talking here? Would a base class with the minimal properties and then some classes inheriting from this with extended properties not suffice? Alternatively instead of assigning properties like Amount a value of 0, make them nullable to be clearer on your intention.

Comment: probably around 100-150 service methods. thinking of having 100+ mostly redundant POCOs in my project makes my head spin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use Nullable Types to indicate the missing properties with a null.

For example:

```
class Order {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public decimal? Amount {get;set;}
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}
```

And then if `Items == null`, it wasn't set. If it's an empty `new List<Item>()`, it's set but empty. Same for `Amount`. If `Amount.HasValue == false`, it wasn't set. If `Amount.Value` is 0.0d, it's set and the item is free.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use LINQ projection?

One service method does something like:

```
return DbContext.Orders.Select(o => new { Id = o.Id, Name = o.Name, Description = o.Description });
```

while the other service method does something like:

```
return DbContext.Orders.Select(o => o);
```

I'm not sure how your application is architected, but this may be a way around creating 100's of POCO's.

Hope this helps!  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in a selector `Func` that returns `dynamic`:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetOrders(Func<Order, dynamic> selector) { ... }
```

I'm not sure how you are accessing data, but the following shows how this would work using a `List<T>`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var service = new Service();
        var orderNames = service.GetOrders(o => new { o.Name });

        foreach (var name in orderNames)
            Console.WriteLine(name.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private List<Order> _orders = new List<Order>
        {
            new Order { Id = 1, Name = "foo", Description = "test order 1", Amount = 1.23m },
            new Order { Id = 2, Name = "bar", Description = "test order 1", Amount = 3.45m },
            new Order { Id = 3, Name = "baz", Description = "test order 1", Amount = 5.67m }
        };

    public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetOrders(Func<Order, dynamic> selector)
    {
        return _orders.Select(selector);
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of nullable values is a good solution, however it has the downside you have no way to matk required fields. That is you cannot use a required attribute on any property. So if there is field that is obligatory in some views you have no way to represent it.
If you don't need required fileds validation this is ok. Otherwise, you need a way to represent which fileds are actually used, and then to write a custom validation provider.

A simple way to do this is to use a "Mask" class with the same property names of the original class, but with all fields boolean: a true values means the field is in use.

I used a similar solution in a system where the properties to be shown are configured in a configuration files...so it was the unique option for me since I had no possibility to represent all combination of properties. HOWEVER, I used the "Mask" class also in the View, so I was able to do all the job with just one View..with a lot of ifs.

Now if your 150 service methods and probably about 150 Views...are all different, then maybe it is simpler to use also several classes ...that is in the worst case 150 classes..the extra work to write them is negligible if compared to the effort of preparing 150 different Views.
However this doesnt mean you need 150 POCO classes. You might use an unique POCO class that is copied into an adequate class just into the presentation Layer. The advantage of this approach is that you can put different validation attributes on the various classes and you don't need to write a custom Validation provider.

Answer (score 1):

Return the entire POCO with nullable types as mentioned by @sbolm.  You can then create a ViewModel per MVC page view that receives a model with the specific properties it needs.  This will take more performance (insignificant) and code, but it keeps your service layer clean, and keeps your views "dumb" in that they are only given what they need and have no direct relation to the service layer.

I.e. (example class from @sbolm)

```
class Order {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public decimal? Amount {get;set;}
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}

// MVC View only needs to know the name and description, manually "map" the POCO properties into this view model and send it to the view

class OrderViewModel {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of modifying the models or creating wrapper models, you have to **name the service methods such that they are self-explanatory** and reveals the consumer what they returns.

The problem with the nullable approach is it makes the user to feel that **the property is not required or mandatory** and they try inserting instances of those types without setting those properties. *Is it won't be bad having nullables every-where?*

It won't be a good approach to change the domain models since all you want is just to populate some of the properties instead of that you create service with names and descriptions that are self-explanatory.

Take the `Order` class itself as the example, say one service method returns the `Order` with all the items and the other one returns only the details of the `Order` but not the items. Then obviously you may have to create two service methods `GetOrderItems` and `GetOrderDetail`, this sounds so simple, yes it is! but notice the service method names itself tells the client what it is going to return. In the `GetOrderDetail` you can return an empty items or null (but here I suggest a null) that doesn't matter much.

So for new cases you don't need to frequently change the models but all you got to do is add or remove the service methods and that's fine. Since you are creating a service you can **create a strong documentation that says what method does what**.

Answer (score 0):

I would not performance optimize this to much unless you realy get performance problems.

I would only distinguish between returning a flat object and an object with  a more complete object graph.

I would have methods returning flat objects called something like GetOrder, GetProduct.

If more complete object graphs are requested they would be called : GetOrderWithDetails.

Do you use the POCO classes for the typed views? If yes: try to make new classes that serve as dedicated ViewModels. These ViewModels would contain POCO classes. This will help you keeping the POCO classes clean.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the nullable idea, you could use the fluentvalidation library to still have validation on the types dependent on whether they are null or not.  This would allow you to have a field be required as long as it was not null or any other validation scheme you can think of.  Example from my own code as I had a similar requirement:

```
Imports FluentValidation

Public Class ParamViewModelValidator
    Inherits AbstractValidator(Of ParamViewModel)

    Public Sub New()
        RuleFor(Function(x) x.TextBoxInput).NotEmpty.[When](Function(x) Not (IsNothing(x.TextBoxInput)))
        RuleFor(Function(x) x.DropdownListInput).NotEmpty.[When](Function(x) Not (IsNothing(x.DropdownListInput)))
    End Sub

End Class
```